# configure React (build) routes.js with Django urls.py

Tags: django, reactjs

I created a web application: `backend` with `Django` & `frontend` with `React`

- in Django I have some views I want to ignore, and let React routes.js handle the urls
- in React I have file `routes.js` I would like to include

After `npm run build` I integrated the `build` folder into my `Django` project.

**I'm able to get to `index.js` in React `build` folder - but the url paths from react routes are not working.**
How I can integrate the routes from my `routes.js` file into the urls?

**`/clients` will take me to the Django view, and `/control` isn't available url**

---

**Project Map**
[image]

**React (original project) > routes.js**

```
...
const BaseRouter = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path='/control' component={Control} />
        <Route exact path='/suppliers' component={Supplier} />
        <Route exact path='/clients' component={ClientsList} />
...
```

**Django > urls.py**

```
...
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

app_name = 'inventory'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    path('clients/', views.filter_clients, name='filter_clients'),
...
```

Comment: You should have Django match all the paths you want to handle with Django views and then pass all other paths to your React app for it to handle the rest. Is there any issue with removing the `clients/` path from Django urls?

Comment: No problem to remove `clients/` - but how can I make the `routes.js` paths to be available?   Right now if I'll remove `clients` and will try to go to the url, it won't be available

Comment: Try moving the React app url to end of your url patterns and make it match all paths. This way any url not handled by a Django view will be passed to your React app

Comment: Yes, that works - Thanks man!
Now the communication with the api on React isn't functioning, but that's another story =/

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by changing:

```py
url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

To:

```py
url(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

Comment: You should use `re_path` in place of `url` as according to the docs `url` is likely to be deprecated in the future https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url